# DCT of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dct

I work on a function in Matlab that calculates the DCT (discrete cosine transform) of an image. I don't know what is not working in my code,which is used in image compression.please help me.
Any ideas please.

```
   clc;close all;clear all;
   image=('cameraman.tif');
    [h w] = size(image);
    image = double(image) - 128;
    b=8;
    block = zeros(b,b);

 image_t=zeros(size(image));
 for k=1:b:h
     for l=1:b:w
        image_t(k:k+b-1,l:l+b-1)= image(k:k+b-1,l:l+b-1);
        for u=1:b
            for v=1:b
                if u == 0
                    Cu = 1/sqrt(2);
                else
                    Cu = 1;
                end
                if v == 0
                    Cv = 1/sqrt(2);
                else
                    Cv = 1;
                end
                Res_sum=0;
                for x=1:b;
                    for y=1:b
                        Res_sum = Res_sum + ((image_t(x,y))*cos(((2*x)+1)*u*pi/(2*b))*cos(((2*y)+1)*v*pi/(2*b)));  
                    end
                end
                dct= (1/4)*Cu*Cv*Res_sum;
                block(u,v) = dct;

            end
        end
        image_comp(k:k+b-1,l:l+b-1)=block(u,v);
     end
 end
end
```

Comment: Why is it not working then?

Comment: Honest comment... If you want other people to review your code, avoid variable names such as h, w, b, v, u, Cu, Cv. They may seem straightforward when you write it, but honestly, when I face a new code and see this, I don't even bother reading it.

Comment: @gdasamu i have implemented by using DCT formula.

Comment: why dont you use the `dct()` function of matlab?

Comment: @articuno i cant use inbuilt function in my program.

Comment: @PrangyaBisoyi are you getting an error ? or are you getting unexpected results ?

Comment: @articuno unexpected result.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you implement the following formula for the DCT:

[image: dct]

with

[image: c(x)]

And I guess you need to divide the image into blocks of `8x8` and do the DCT on each of these blocks.

1. Please comment your code! It helps you and others understand it much better!
2. You can never reach the part inside `if u == 0` or `if v == 0`, as you go through `u` and `v` in for loops which run through `1:b`. The underlying problem is that MATLAB starts indexing at 1, while the frequencies in the DCT start at 0. My hint: Use `u` and `v` as frequency as in the formula, not like index, i.e. `for u=0:b-1` and use `u+1` when indexing.
3. The same for `x` and `y`.
4. `image_t` should only contain the current block (i thus renamed it to `current_block`) and not the whole image. That's `current_block = image(k:k+b-1,l:l+b-1);`
5. In the line `dct= (1/4)*Cu*Cv*Res_sum;`, it should not be `1/4` but rather `1/sqrt(2*N)` where `N` is your block size (you call it `b`), thus `1/sqrt(2*b)`. For a block size of `8`, as in your example, this is of course `1/4`.
6. `image` is the name of a MATLAB function. It is advisable not to use it as a function name. Consider changing it e.g. to `input_image`.
7. I am not sure why you subtract `128` from the input image, please overthink why you are doing that.

That leads to the code below. I don't know if that solves *all* your problem, but you should be much closer to that now ;-)

PS: Consider vectorization of the code for improved performance.

```
function image_comp = dctII(input_image, b)
    [h, w] = size(input_image);
    input_image = double(input_image);
    block_dct = zeros(b);

    % Loop through all blocks
    for k=1:b:h
      for l=1:b:w

        % Save true image of block
        current_block = input_image(k:k+b-1,l:l+b-1);

        % Loop through all cos frequencies (u,v)
        for u=0:b-1
          for v=0:b-1
            if u == 0
                Cu = 1/sqrt(2);
            else
                Cu = 1;
            end
            if v == 0
                Cv = 1/sqrt(2);
            else
                Cv = 1;
            end

            Res_sum = 0;

            % Loop through all pixel values
            for x=0:b-1
              for y=0:b-1
                Res_sum = Res_sum + ((current_block(x+1,y+1))*cos(((2*x)+1)*u*pi/(2*b))*cos(((2*y)+1)*v*pi/(2*b)));  
              end
            end

            % Calculate DCT value at frequency (u,v)
            dct = 1/sqrt(2*b) * Cu * Cv * Res_sum;
            block_dct(u+1,v+1) = dct;
          end
        end

        image_comp(k:k+b-1,l:l+b-1) = block_dct(u+1,v+1);

      end
    end
end         % of function
```

Comment: thanks a lot ,i have subtract 128 from original image as i have done level shifting so that i can perform dct as it value range between (-128 to 127).

Comment: This was more work than necessary. +1. I'm not inclined to help this OP as he/she seems like a *give me teh coodz* kind of person.